# How to make Odoo form readonly when the record has an specific state?

Tags: python, odoo

I have an entity "payment" in Odoo that has several states. I want to open the form of a payment in readonly mode (disable edit button) when that payment has the state "paid". How do I do that?

Comment: I found it here: https://www.odoo.com/id_ID/forum/help-1/how-to-hide-edit-button-in-purchase-order-for-specific-states-128804

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way is to add readonly attribute to all the fields, like this:

```
<field name="my_field" attrs="{'readonly':[('state','=','paid')]}"/>
```

but if you still want to hide the edit button, then you need to override the form controller, here's how:

1. Create a javascript file in your module static folder:
   my_module/static/src/js/my_form_view.js
2. Add this inside the my_form_view.js:

```
odoo.define('my_module.MyCustomForm', function (require) {
"use strict";

    var FormController = require('web.FormController');
    var viewRegistry = require('web.view_registry');
    var FormView = require('web.FormView');

    var MyFormController = FormController.extend({
        _updateButtons: function () {
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            if (this.$buttons) {
                if (this.renderer.state.data.state !== 'paid'){
                    this.$buttons.find('.o_form_button_edit').show();
                } else {
                    this.$buttons.find('.o_form_button_edit').hide();
                }
            }            
        },

    });

    var MyFormView = FormView.extend({
        config: _.extend({}, FormView.prototype.config, {
            Controller: MyFormController,
        }),
    });
    viewRegistry.add('custom_form', MyFormView);

});
```

3. add your js script to asset backend, by creating a new file, my_module/views/asset.xml, and the content should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<odoo>

    <template id="assets_backend" name="my_backend_assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/my_module/static/src/js/my_form_view.js" />
        </xpath>
    </template>

</odoo>
```

4. also you need to add your custom form view to the form view, like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="my_model_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">my.model.form</field>
        <field name="model">my.model</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form js_class="custom_form">
            ... your form contents
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
        
</odoo>
```

Comment: I supose 'custom_form' is the external ID of my form and i should use
 if (this.renderer.state.data.state === 'paid') wich is the state of the payment

Comment: How do I added to the asset backend

Comment: it worked  but when I open that form from an action (caused by a button clic) like this
  return {
            'name': name,
            'res_model': my_model,
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'res_id': record_id,
            'context': {
                'inconsistencia_id': self.id
            },
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'target': 'new'
        }
it show the error:  
TypeError: this.$buttons is undefined

http://localhost:8069/web/content/516-7021dfa/web.assets_backend.js:321

Comment: ahh, i see, it probably was a pop up modal, it doesn't have a control panel therefore the buttons, just put a check on it, i updated the answer

Comment: thank you so much for your help. One last question: Is it possible to hide the "save" and "discart buttons from the pop up modal when I click the One2Many item? I cannot edit the fields but those buttons are still showing "

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a new form which would be starting as following:

```xml
<!-- consider the xml id for this form view is small_module.my_custom_form -->
<form create="false" edit="false">
</form>
```

then in your action you will call such form.

```xml
<record id="my_custom_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">The Best Action</field>
    <field name="res_model">custom.model.action</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="small_module.my_custom_form"/>
</record>
```

or you could return such action in a Python method.

```py
return {
    'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
    'name': _('The Best Action'),
    'view_type': 'form',
    'view_mode': 'tree,form',
    'res_model': 'custom.model.action',
    'view_id': self.env.ref('small_module.my_custom_form').id,
}
```

Comment: how it will work if the state changes? To set create/edit False it will execute for all the way, no such specific condition would be grant,