# how to hide edit button in view form (Odoo v13)

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I would like to know the way to hide the "edit" button from the form view when it is in a specific state

for example:
In the help desk I have the states that are shown in the image, I want the edit button to be completely hidden from all people when it goes to "closed" state

[image]

Comment: There is no easy way to do it odoo don't handle this case

Comment: Mi solution is: # Add Html Field

test_css = fields.Html(string='CSS', sanitize=False, compute='_compute_css', store=False)


# Add compute function
@api.depends('state')
def _compute_css(self):
for record in self:
    # You can modify the below below condition
    if record.state != 'draft':
        record.test_css = '<style>.o_form_button_edit {display: none !important;}</style>'
    else:
        record.test_css = False


<!--Finally Add the field in the form view-->

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in a specific form you can change your form element with the below line:

```
<form edit="false" >
```

If you want to do it globally you will need to do it from js code.

Answer (score 1):

**Add Html Field**

```
test_css = fields.Html(string='CSS', sanitize=False, compute='_compute_css', store=False)
```

**Add compute function**

```
@api.depends('state')
def _compute_css(self):
for record in self:
    # You can modify the below below condition
    if record.state != 'draft':
        record.test_css = '<style>.o_form_button_edit {display: none !important;}</style>'
    else:
        record.test_css = False
```

**Finally Add the field in the form view**

```
<field name="test_css" invisible="1"/>
```

Here is the screenshot of [sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHrrk.png)

Comment: a smart and very easy way to do it. I never thinked of this before even I used similar solution by using the power of HTML field

Answer (score 0):

Let s try this idea ?
Create a new field in the same model class of your status pipeline

```py
is_closed = fields.Boolean('is closed', readonly=True)

     @api.onchange('stage_id')  # triggered fields
      def on_change_stage_id(self):      
         if self.stage_id == 'closed':
           self.is_closed = True
         else:
           self.is_closed = False
```

In the corresponding model view:

```xml
      <odoo>
      <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_mymodel_form_extend">
            <field name="name">event.view_mymodel_form_xsb</field>
            <field name="model">mymodel.mymodel</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="originalmodel.view_originalmodel_form"/>       
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <data>     
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='name']" position="after"> 
                  <field name="is_closed" string="is closed" />
                </xpath>
```

...which will display a checkbox in the  in your html page.

You can now use the onchange method on this new input field, using jquery code in your custom file: src/user/my_module/static/src/js/disable_edit.js

```js
    odoo.define('my_module.disable_edit', function(require) {
    "use strict";

    $(document).ready(function() {

       $("input[name='is_closed']").on('change', function() {
         //if($("nav.o_main_navbar>a.o_menu_brand").text()=='Sale')
         
           if (($(this).val == "True")
             {
              $(".button.o_form_button_edit").hide();
             }
           else
             {
              $(".button.o_form_button_edit").show();
             }
         

         });
       });
     });
```

Comment: Hello, My stage_id is type meny2one and button is "Edit" native from Odoo

Comment: Let's have a look here too : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65948282/how-to-make-odoo-form-readonly-when-the-record-has-an-specific-state?rq=1

Comment: and here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31014443/how-to-hide-the-edit-button-form-based-on-state-field-of-invoice-odoo-v8?rq=1

Comment: estoy intentando como indican en los links que me indicas pero no me funciona, he intentado de varias formas

Comment: in fact, onchange() is only triggered for <input> tags included in a <form> and not <button> tags